# Como usar o canvas e o SimpleDocTemplate mutuamente? (reportlab)

Tags: table, canvas, reportlab

Eu estou a fazer a exportação de relatórios através da biblioteca **reportlab**.
Para inserir o texto eu usei o módulo canvas, e escrivi este código que funciona bem.

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

pdf = canvas.Canvas('exemple3.pdf', pagesize=A4)

pdf.setFillColor(aColor='blue')
pdf.setFont('Helvetica', 14)
pdf.drawString(55, 740, 'RELATÓRIO FEVEREIRO 2021')

pdf.setFillColor(aColor='black')
pdf.setFont('Helvetica', 22)
pdf.drawString(55, 715, 'PROJECTOS')
pdf.drawString(55, 695, 'MINOR HOTEL GROUP')
pdf.drawString(55, 675, 'HOTÉIS TIVOLI PORTUGAL')
pdf.save()
```

De seguida eu vou precisar de inserir uma tabela no PDF e para isso eu descobri que o módulo SimpleDocTemplate poderia-me ajudar e por isso criei o seguinte código que funciona bem separado do anterior:

```
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle

elements = []

data= [['Periodo a que diz respeito', startdate + ' a ' + enddate],
       [' ', ' '],
       ['Horas despendidas no período de 01/01/2021 a 20/01/2021', '271,04'],
       ['Por rubrica:', ' ']]

t=Table(data)
t.setStyle(TableStyle([('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                       ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                       ('ALIGN',(1,1),(-3,-3),'RIGHT'),
                       ('VALIGN',(0,-1),(-1,-1),'MIDDLE'),
                       ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0),(1,-1),colors.black)]))
elements.append(t)
pfd.build(elements)
```

A minha questão é como posso juntar estes dois códigos?
Se tiver outra solução agradeço :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não vamos juntar o método Canvas com o SimpleDocTemplate, não faz sentido.
Depois de várias pesquisas aquilo que ententi é que o Canvas é ótimo para gerar texto, documentos mais simples e para inicialmente perceber um pouco da biblioteca **reportlab**

A solução que eu arranjei foi a seguinte:

Importei mais estas duas variantes do reportlab e mantive o mesmo código para gerar a tabela.

```
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle

elements = []

data= [['Periodo a que diz respeito', startdate + ' a ' + enddate],
       [' ', ' '],
       ['Horas despendidas no período de 01/01/2021 a 20/01/2021', '271,04'],
       ['Por rubrica:', ' ']]

t=Table(data)
t.setStyle(TableStyle([('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                       ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                       ('ALIGN',(1,1),(-3,-3),'RIGHT'),
                       ('VALIGN',(0,-1),(-1,-1),'MIDDLE'),
                       ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0),(1,-1),colors.black)]))
```

O texto está a ser adicionado ao array **elements** através da variável **Paragraph** do reportlab. A variável style é a que vai dar outro aspeto a este texto.

```
style = ParagraphStyle('heading1',
                       fontName = 'Helvetica-Bold',
                       fontSize = 20,
                       textColor = colors.black,
                       leading = 20)

elements.append(Paragraph('RELATÓRIO FEVEREIRO 2021', style))
elements.append(Paragraph('PROJECTOS', style))
elements.append(Paragraph('TIVOLI HOTEIS', style))

elements.append(t)#adiciona a tabela à variavel elements

pdf = SimpleDocTemplate('exemple3.pdf', pagesize=A4)
pfd.build(elements)
```

Por fim o 'pdf.build(elements)' irá adicionar o texto e a tabela ao relatório PDF, com as formatações configuradas.

Sou nova por aqui, desculpem se não expliquei bem. Estão à vontade para fazer perguntas.